# How did the Basilisk survive for a thousand years?

Tags: harry-potter, basilisk

The lifespan of a Basilisk might be thousands of years, but how can one survive without eating anything for thousands of years?

Comment: A Wizard Did It...

Comment: It's a magical creature, it may not need to eat at all.

Comment: Spiders revere the basilisk.  I imagine Aragog's lot has been bringing it food all the time, presumably small game from the forest.

Comment: @b_jonas Uh, no. Spiders are terrified of it. It is their hated enemy. A creature that kills with eye contact is not revered among a species that has eight unblinking eyes.

Comment: @GabeWillard: sorry, you're right.  CS says “Spiders flee before the Basilisk, for it is there mortal enemy, and the Basilisk flees only from the crowing of the rooster, which is fatal to it.”

Comment: See the related question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46395/ What did Smaug eat for 60 years?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> The Basilisk is a brilliant green serpent that may reach up to fifty feet in length. The male has a scarlet plume upon its head. It has exceptionally venomous fangs but its most dangerous meansof attack is the gaze of its large yellow eyes. Anyone looking directly into these will suffer instant death.
>   If the food source is sufficient (the Basilisk will eat all mammals and birds and most reptiles), the serpent may attain a very great age. Herpo the Foul’s Basilisk is believed to have lived for close on nine hundred years.
>   <sub>*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* - Newt Scamander - pages 3-4</sub>

and

> But the tunnel was quiet as the grave, and the first unexpected sound they heard was a loud *crunch* as Ron stepped on what turned out to be a rat’s skull. Harry lowered his wand to look at the floor and saw that it was littered with small animal bones.
>   <sub>*Chamber of Secrets* - page 223 - UK Hardcover - chapter 16, *The Chamber of Secrets*</sub>

*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* explains that Basilisks stay alive by eating any and all mammals, birds, and most reptiles. Page 223 of *Chamber of Secrets* notes the presence of numerous animal remains. I don't interpret this to be incidental; J.K. Rowling noted the animal remains because it was the Basilisk who'd left them there, as opposed to noting casually, "Oh, the outer chamber was nicely decorated in rocks, dirt, slime on the walls, and animal skeletons."

I believe that is your canon answer: The animal remains were left by the Basilisk over the years, as it ate mammals, birds, and some reptiles to survive. That might be a boring answer, but, well, I believe it's the canon explanation.

Comment: Snakes digest bones, one would assume the Basilisk does as well, so the animals who the skeletons belong to may have been killed by the Basilisk, but were not eaten by it. This of course does not preclude the fact that the most reasonable answer is that it did eat some animals that stumbled in.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would downvote this; this is straight from canon, and a direct explanation of how it survived. Anyone who doesn't like this answer should go downvote JK Rowling.

Comment: @GabeWillard I downvoted for the reasons explained in my comment; one might even say that the evidence of skeletal remains of animals on the floor is direct evidence against the Basilisk eating them.

Comment: And you are assuming, against provided canon, that a Basilisk digests its food identically to a snake. Fantasy is not reality. Your point is utterly irrelevant, considering that *we are not talking about a snake*. We are talking about a plumed [serpent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serpent), who is hatched from a chicken egg under a toad.

Comment: @GabeWillard ... you do realize that the definition that you linked to has 1b. SNAKE? I grant you that fantasy is not reality, however I am inclined to believe that the Basilisk's digestion is more similar to snakes OR serpants, than to other animals. I still think that the Basilisk likely ate small animals that it came across in the chamber, but this answer makes an (IMO) incorrect assumption that bones = meals.

Comment: A snake is always a serpent; a serpent is not always a snake. The thing is, this answer has basis in **canon**. Your opinion does not.

Comment: @GabeWillard and yet the definition *you* gave me for serpent says snake. I think this is actually an excellent answer, but just that it needs some tweaking to state something along the lines of "since there are animal bones in the chamber, it is safe to assume that the Basilisk had a steady supply of animals to eat, enough so that it did not need to digest all of them." The bones show canonically that the Basilisk had a steady supply of food, my only issue is that the animal bones *most likely* indicate that they were not digested.

Comment: The word serpent originates from the Latin language; it meant a legless reptile. Not all legless reptiles are necessarily snakes; legendary dragons fell into this category. All snakes are legless reptiles. Misapplied semantics aside, there is no **canon support** for a Basilisk digesting bones.

Comment: @GabeWillard I am not feeling particularly argumentative today and have to leave actually, but I will leave you with the fact that the definition you gave me has basis in **fact**. Your opinion does not.

Comment: Were these skeletons the remains of students' familiars? How many rats, cats, toads etc would a basilisk need to eat to stay alive? No one mentions the need to replace their animal fairly frequently.

Comment: @NominSim - Yeah, I'll just take the -2. I'm not applying the physiology of a Muggle snake to a *Basilisk*.

Comment: @NiceOrc -- I don't know. Perhaps you could it as a separate question. Canon doesn't address any of those issues.

Comment: @GabeWillard From the book, which I hope you'll understand to be canon: "Of the many fearsome beasts and monsters that roam our land, there is none more curious or more deadly than the Basilisk, known also as the King of Serpents. This **snake**, which may reach gigantic size..." I don't expect to sway your opinion, but the Basilisk is a snake, and that canonical evidence points towards it eating food like a snake.

Comment: @NominSim There is always the possibility that JK Rowling intended the Basilisk to be a snake (the evidence you quoted seems conclusive!), but didn't know snakes digest bones. Doesn't seem like a major mistake :)

Comment: @AndresF. I completely agree, I think that to be a likely case too actually. I wasn't trying to be difficult with this answer or anything, just wanted to mention that the Basilisk was called a snake in the book, and that snakes digest bones. Just thought it should have been taken into account is all :)

Comment: @Gabe The meaning of the Latin word _serpēns_ is quite irrelevant to what the English word _serpent_ means. They are different words. Defining one based on the other is what is known as the Etymological Fallacy. And _serpēns_ in Latin did not specifically mean ‘legless reptile’. It meant ‘creeper/crawler’: it is simply a nominalised use of the present participle of _serpō_ ‘to creep/crawl’. _Serpēns_ was also used for lice and other things that would certainly be neither serpents nor snakes in English.

Answer (score 12):

I'm pretty sure that in the book it states that there are the bones of dead animals all over the place as Harry is entering the chamber.

Comment: And in the movie they step on the bones when they first slide down into the tunnels

Comment: This explains nothing... Those bones might be thousands years older.

Comment: It's a perfectly plausible explanation.  And I'm sure you can find a way to exclude any plausible answer given.  But it's all fantasy, so why the sudden skepticism?

Comment: Snakes digest bones...

Comment: Post owls. Yum. Please send more.

Comment: @NominSim Basilisk wasn't a snake..

Comment: @SachinShekhar From the book, "Of the many fearsome beasts and monsters that roam our land, there is none more curious or more deadly than the Basilisk, known also as the King of Serpents. This **snake**, which may reach gigantic size..."

Comment: @NominSim Its a style of literature..

Comment: @NominSim: So you're willing to believe that a snake can live for 900 years and kill with their gaze, but the concept of a snake that spits out bones is a bridge too far?

Answer (score 8):

Snakes can often live for a year between meals, if they get something significant. I would suspect that ( as per @AlisdairCM ), some animals would always find their way into its lair, and it lived off them.

As a magical creature, it can probably survive on less that you might expect. One student a year surely wouldn't be missed ..... ;)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in my [answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/35104/13418), I will post my point of view here.

Remember that the Chamber of Secret (and most importantly the basilisk) was a vengeance device. Slytherin didn't plan any movement mean for the Basilisk because when he left Hogwart, I guess the basilisk was still an egg. He designed this room as a tool for the use of a future heir of his. I strongly think that the basilisk was not put there as a "splinter cell" murderer, but as a war weapon.

Riddle did release the basilisk once, but before that the basilisk was probably in a magic sleep state, thus not needing to move.

So, although it is only supposition, I always believed that the Basilisk was not 1000-year-old but 50-year-old. After all, when Harry enters the Chamber, he sees one dead skin. A 1000-year-old basilisk would have produced a lot more (personnal guess).

Answer (score 3):

Why does everyone assume the basilisk was trapped in the chamber? The way you get in and out of the chamber is by speaking parseltongue. Snake or not, the basilisk speaks parseltongue.

It's entirely possible that it has been going out into the forest and eating things it finds there the entire time, and only goes after humans when specifically directed to do so. It would make sense for it's original instructions to have been something along those lines when Slytherin was actually alive.

It also makes more sense of the bones -  remember that the bones and the skin were between the bathroom pipe entrance and the doors, which needed a password. Slytherin's face also needed a password to open. So the basilisk had to pass those two obstacles before it could leave the skin and bones there.

Also, I realize that the story is all about Slytherin's heir releasing the monster from the chamber, but first - even in the book's world that's definitely a legend. Even the fact that the monster was a basilisk had been forgotten or had never been part of the legend at all. It needing to be released from the chamber might have been an addition to the story, or it might only apply when you are directing it to attack someone, etc. Who can tell for sure with a story that old.