# How was Basilisk so stealthy?

Tags: harry-potter, basilisk

Let's put aside the question of how a huge snake could fit into the Hogwarts water pipes (they're magical pipes!) and exit them at random points (there are magical pipes/walls with built in portals only a basilisk can open!) to attack isolated Muggleborns (how would a snake know the difference?) unfortunate enough to be isolated (they really should've known better!)

My question is: How is it possible for a 60 ft long snake not to been seen by anyone/anything (for a giant snake it sure was a master of hit and run)? Even though there are hundreds of portraits everywhere through the castle, at least a hundred of house elves working all over the castle, and at least 20 ghosts roaming around (according to Ch7 of PS). Even if direct eye contact is necessary for a true kill and indirect eye contact (i.e. reflections) results  in petrification, how is it possible that not a single soul saw it while it was *retreating* to the pipes? Not a single portrait/elf/ghost told Dumbledore "Hey headmaster I just saw a 30 ft long scaly something disappearing through wall/to a nearest bathroom, but I didn't see its face."

Comment: While this is a question that I also have wondered, it is not answerable by canon and calls for pure conjecture. I hate to VTC, but in this instance you're asking us to speculate and basically list plot holes. This is not a site for theories. This is a site for definitive answers that can be substantiated by canon. Sorry, but I feel a VTC is appropriate.

Comment: @Slytherincess Ok. I thought that maybe there was some answer I missed...

Comment: @Fen1ks - For reference, you may get some of your answers from [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13000/how-could-hogwarts-have-realistically-accommodated-the-basilisk-800-1000-year?rq=1) question

Comment: Related meta discussions: [Should all questions without explicit canon answers be closed?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3014/5184) and [What makes this question not constructive, but these others OK?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3011/5184)

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49375/4918 How did the Basilisk manage to travel and kill? My answer to that one might answer this too.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the Basilisk just didn't leave the pipes, except for its head. Staying inside the pipes, it could avoid everything. It went to find its target, then simply poked its head out, attacked, and went back in. The portraits might have seen something, but it seems to me their gaze would be more along the hallways. It seems like the attacks all happened near Bathrooms, and there was always a puddle of water around. However the Basilisk made the attacks, it didn't wander much outside of the plumbing, and for whatever reason, the pictures didn't see it.

Comment: But _how_ would the basilisk poke it's head through the ceiling or wall? While I was reading the book I assumed it would always enter the corridor through the nearest 'parseltounge operated toilet' :), sneak (we already established it's ninja skills) to the target, lock eyes with them (or attempt to) and run back to nearest exit.

Comment: the lesson they learned was "beware of the bathrooms" (at least the ones outside your tower) :)

Comment: They were probably avoiding Moaning Myrtle.  She wasn't restricted to the one bathroom, after all...

Comment: @Izkata Well Myrtle **is** scary :)

Answer (score 2):

Given the way portraits work in the Potter universe, nobody would want portraits in or near the bathrooms, for privacy's sake. So the portraits would not have been able to witness the basilisk attacks. Harry and Hermione were not aware of House Elves at Hogwarts until well into the second book, so elves cleaning the bathroom would not have been doing so when the children were about, and been able to witness the basilisk's emergence. And there was one ghost who saw the basilisk--Nick, who became a victim.

Comment: Considering that they have a portrait of a mermaid **inside of** a Prefects' bathroom (in Ch25 of GoF - yes, in book it's a portrait _not_ a mosaic) I don't think that's necessarily true; Nick saw the Basilisk face to face, I was wondering why no one saw it _retreating_? As for house-elves, nowhere in the book is explicitly stated they work at night, only that the kids tend not to notice them. But this was as good guess as any