# A story that has waste-removing spells

Tags: story-identification, magic

I need some help identifying a book once recommended to me.

Unfortunately, I can't remember much about this book. However, the one detail I can remember is rather unique.

In this world, the Wizards do not need to use the bathroom, because they magically zap all their waste to an unspecified dimension/location.
Any ideas on what this book may have been?

Comment: If it helps, that concept (minus magic, substitute technology) was used in the Family Guy episode '[Road to the Multiverse](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Road_to_the_Multiverse).' (Specifically, it was in the '[Universe without Christianity](http://familyguy.wikia.com/wiki/Universe_Without_Christianity).)'

Comment: Do you remember when this was recommended to you? i.e. the 90s, 2000s, or just recently?  Do you have a rough publication date?

Comment: Sorry. I really don't have any information other than the waste spell. It came up in a discussion about obscure magic uses, and that's when he told me about the book in question, and recommended I reas it.

Comment: The Inda series by Sherwood Smith? People use the 'waste spell' for bodily functions, and 'wanding' for animal waste, etc.

Comment: @Frock Yes! That's it! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Will post as an answer, then.

Comment: Is it the Pottermore story quoted in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/59579/4918 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *[Inda](http://www.sherwoodsmith.net/sartorias-deles/inda-banner/)* series by Sherwood Smith.

From the author's [glossary](http://www.sherwoodsmith.net/sartorias-deles/glossary/):

**WASTE SPELL**: The simple definition is that these few syllables, whispered when a human being lets go of waste, gets rid of it. Waste includes vomit, and with a syllable attached, menses. The Spell dates back to the earliest days after humans first found themselves on this world, and the indigenous beings, discovering that not only were humans fast befouling the environment they were making themselves sick, communicated the connection to the early mages, who, when they comprehended the connection, not only arranged for this magic (for the curious, the waste is broken down chemically and transported deep underground), they arranged for spells that could be performed over specific items, such as buckets, that not just cleaned the water of bacteria, but cleaned items dipped into the buckets.

**WANDING**: Wands have spells on them to break down and transfer animal waste underground.