# Are toilets renovated at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Bathrooms at Hogwarts have water closets and porcelain faucets, which are relatively modern inventions, considering Hogwarts was founded over 1000 years ago. Are the toilets magical, and upgrade themselves to modern standards, or have they been renovated (by house-elves, I suppose)? How often do the renovations happen?

Comment: Toilets really? :P

Comment: Until quite recently witches and wizards just used to crap wherever they stood, then use magic to clean it up. #CanonFacts

Comment: See the related https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/59579/4918 about Hogwarts and plumbing.

Comment: Ah, seems like a duplicate then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Could Hogwarts Have Realistically Accommodated the Basilisk 800 - 1000+ Years Ago?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13000/how-could-hogwarts-have-realistically-accommodated-the-basilisk-800-1000-year)

Comment: I absolutely love pooped like a horse "fact". I don't think I will forget that one any time soon. Muggles have had plumbing of some kind in B.C. Wizards just plopped a  deuce in the library and proofed it away. Unless you were young and learning then it might just explode everywhere.

Comment: @Valorum: following that logic they should have extended baby diapers to magic adult diapers.

Comment: Flagged to migrate to Academia.SE

Comment: @Valorum it makes you really consider the purpose of the robes.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Modern-style toilets were only added to Hogwarts during the 18th century:

> When first created, the Chamber was accessed through a concealed trapdoor and a series of magical tunnels. However, when Hogwarts’ plumbing became more elaborate in the eighteenth century (this was a rare instance of wizards copying Muggles, because hitherto they simply relieved themselves wherever they stood, and vanished the evidence), the entrance to the Chamber was threatened, being located on the site of a proposed bathroom. The presence in school at the time of a student called Corvinus Gaunt – direct descendant of Slytherin, and antecedent of Tom Riddle – explains how the simple trapdoor was secretly protected, so that those who knew how could still access the entrance to the Chamber even after newfangled plumbing had been placed on top of it.
>
> (Pottermore, [Chamber of Secrets](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/chamber-of-secrets))

Whoever did the upgrade is unknown.

Comment: _relieved themselves wherever they stood, and vanished the evidence_ Oh God, I can't believe the spell they taught for _that_

Comment: "Evanesco faeces"?

Comment: The Chamber of Secrets was originally accessible from the Chamber of Pots.

Comment: In fact, its original name was The Chamber of Secretions.

Comment: @Hellion You mean Chamber of Excretions.

Comment: The Chamber of Excretions is where the Philosopher's Log was found.

Comment: How is this possible? That Rowling story-covered the toilets...

Comment: `Wand be true, please don't miss and get rid of this piss.`

Comment: `Red trap, bear trap, please get rid of this pile of crap.`

Comment: `Now be strong, my wand of gum, and get rid of this...` oh you get my point.